# Monit: 'Matching' functionality isn't working

Tags: bash, monit

I have a process that's kicked off from a custom script. The process does not end with '.pid' so I am trying to use 'matching'. However it seems to be breaking on the whitespace (just stops after 'bin/bash'), no matter how I format the command. The commands themselves do work fine, outside of monit.

Here is what I am trying to use:

```
check process example_process matching "example_process"
start program = "/bin/bash -c 'nohup /mnt1/path/to/custom/bin/run.sh &'"
stop program = "/usr/bin/killall example_process"
    if cpu > 80% for 2 cycles then alert
    if cpu > 95% for 5 cycles then restart
    if totalmem > 500.0 MB for 5 cycles then restart
    if children > 3 then restart
```

Errors logged:

```
[UTC Jun 18 02:01:46] info     : 'system_ip-10-0-11-189' Monit started
[UTC Jun 18 02:01:46] error    : 'example_process' process is not running
[UTC Jun 18 02:01:46] info     : 'example_process' trying to restart
[UTC Jun 18 02:01:46] info     : 'example_process' start: /bin/bash
[UTC Jun 18 02:02:16] error    : 'example_process' failed to start
```